# Does DynamoDB's mapper support querying for an auto-generated key?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

This article about the AWS SDK for Java says that it can automatically generate a key in a data class through `@DynamoDBAutoGenerateKey`:
https://aws.amazon.com/articles/0802321832592496

Question is, how do I load something like this based on that key? If I construct an object with that ID and call `.load()` with it, will it automatically look up the correct hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats correct.

Eg with a mapper:

```
DynamoDBMapperConfig mapperConfig = DynamoDBMapperConfig
                    .builder()                
                    .withTableNameOverride(DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNamePrefix(environment + "."))
                    .withConversionSchema(ConversionSchemas.V2)
                    .build();

client.getMapper().load(DBActivity.class, id, mapperConfig)
```

Where, id is the auto-generated key.

Comment: Well I wouldn't know what the auto-generated key is, it's a hash generated from my object's private member. If I use the same member for a load, will it still work?

Comment: You wont know the auto generated value for any of the databases you implement. The generated value needs to be returned to the caller, after you issue the create call. Its the api callers responsibility to provide the right key to act upon.